# Ubuntu becomes extremely slow after running Machine Learning training program

Tags: performance

I wrote the program in question in C++ for a lab course. Up until now I only ran it on a toy corpus without problems, but today I used a big, real-life training corpus, on which the program ran for a few hours. Not only did the computer seem to get progressively slower in processing the data as time went on, it was slow to the point of being unusable when the program finished.

I'm not going to guarantee that my program is bugfree but the problems persisted after the process terminated and I closed the console, so I doubt that it's a memory leak bug or something like that on my end. Any ideas what could have happened? Running an Intel i7 quad core, 16 GB RAM.

Comment: It could have pushed a lot of stuff into swap space from RAM, which would slow your system down in general. What does `free -h` say (paste into question, select text, press `{}` button to format nicely)?

Comment: A memory leak could still be the cause (and likely is), as things probably started swapping, which would mean using disk for memory. This is extremely slow, and if the shell application got pushed into swap, it's likely still there. A reboot would resolve it, but memory usage should probably be optimized better in your program. You can also use `ulimit` to limit the amount of memory the program can use, which might help you debug where the leak is happening, and can help prevent the issue from recurring.